# Sonar java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create ClassLoader

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

My Office user Sonar 4.4, I just have had a problem with it. This is the error return from the log :

```
[INFO] [10:50:32.770] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [10:50:32.770] 4 source files to be analyzed
[ERROR] [10:50:32.841] Unable to create symbol table for : Entry.java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create ClassLoader
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder.create(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:61) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.getClassLoader(BytecodeCompleter.java:112) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.inputStreamFor(BytecodeCompleter.java:107) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:187) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:129) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:55) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:80) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:67) [sslr-core-1.20.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:118) [java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:83) [java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:135) [java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:128) [java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86) [sonar-java-plugin-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:217) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:217) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:212) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:210) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:205) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:110) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:185) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch8326487844145392374.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135) [sonar-maven-plugin-2.6.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132) [sonar-maven-plugin-2.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) [maven-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) [maven-embedder-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) [maven-embedder-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) [maven-embedder-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open C:\.m2\repository\com\kartuku\iam\common\1.1.0\common-1.1.0.jar
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.loader.JarLoader.<init>(JarLoader.java:50) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.loader.SquidClassLoader.<init>(SquidClassLoader.java:50) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder.create(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:59) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:117) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.loader.JarLoader.<init>(JarLoader.java:47) ~[java-squid-2.4.jar:na]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

It was worked before but suddenly return that error. My sonar admin said that there isn't any config change. This is the return when it was worked :

```
[INFO] [16:40:52.930] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [16:40:52.931] 4 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [16:40:53.841] Java Main Files AST scan done: 911 ms
[INFO] [16:40:53.843] Java bytecode scan...
[INFO] [16:40:53.857] 4/4 source files analyzed
[WARN] [16:40:54.041] Class 'com/kartuku/iam/common/model/User' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [16:40:54.043] Class 'com/kartuku/iam/persistence/entity/Account' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [16:40:54.044] Class 'com/kartuku/iam/common/model/User' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [16:40:54.044] Class 'com/kartuku/iam/persistence/entity/Account' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [16:40:54.044] Class 'com/kartuku/iam/common/model/User' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

NB : the sonar analysis running via jenkins

Any Explaination?
Thanks before

Comment: `Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file` this is your rootcause....

Comment: You are using a very old version of the java plugin 2.4, please use a more recent version ( latest release is 3.5 at time of writing ) and tell us if it still does not work. Moreover, as pointed out by CodeBender it seems that the jar file is not unzipped properly, so please double check that this file is not corrupted.

Comment: I think something with jar files in my .m2 repository for this application. All of them are damaged. I even cannot open it manually with winrar, meanwhile it works in other aplication.

Comment: Any news on that ?  I have the exact same problem while running via jenkins.  In my case, I use the sonar maven plugin, not the jenkins plugin.
From the stack, I cannot see wich jar are the problem.  But the analyse continues (don't fail).

Comment: I do not really understand the root cause, but clearly the repo was the problem. I deleted my .m2 repo and let my application recreate it, but that wasn't worked. I tried everything, and after change the application version in the pom.xml and maven will create new repo. That's works.

I do not know why, I just tried everything. :D